# How to give long paths in java runtime exec method?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\AutoIt3\\autoit3.exe ./WindowsAuthenticationLogin.au3");
```

in java

But failing and displaying fail message as

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program"
```

Please tell me how can I give correct path to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path needs to have escaped quotes around it if it contains spaces. Alternately, for `Program Files` directory, you can also use this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Progra~1\\AutoIt3\\autoit3.exe ./WindowsAuthenticationLogin.au3");`

Comment: Thanks it worked, I put "Program Files" as "Progra~1"

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the first space with `\\`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program\\ Files\\AutoIt3\\autoit3.exe ./WindowsAuthenticationLogin.au3");
```